# Как в woocommerce в карточке товара вывести все вариации без пагинации?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, настройка

Как в woocommerce в карточке товара вывести все вариации без пагинации? По умолчанию отображается только 15 вариаций на странице и их сортировка вручную из-за нескольких страниц не получается.

Answer (score 2):

Вукомерс задает параметр так

```
$variations_per_page    = absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 15 ) );
```

т.е поменять можно через functions.php примерно так:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_meta_boxes_variations_per_page', 'new_variations_per_page');
function new_variations_per_page($per_page){
    $per_page = 100; //-1 Выводит 1 товар
    return $per_page;
}
```